# S3 — Auto generate folder structure?

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

I need to store user uploaded files in Amazon S3. I'm new to S3, but as I got from docs, S3 requires of me to specify file upload path in PUT method.

I'm wondering if there is a way to send file to S3, and simply get link for http(s) access?  I wish Amazon to handle all headache related to file/folder structure itself. For example, I just pipe from node.js file to S3, and on callback I get http link with no expiration date. And Amazon itself creates smth like `/2014/12/01/.../$hash.jpg` and just returns me the final link? Such use case looks to be quite common.

Is it possible? If no, could you suggest any options to simplify file storage/filesystem tree structure in S3?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesnt' have folders, actually. In a normal filesystem, `2014/12/01/blah.jpg` would mean you've got a `2014` folder with a folder called `12` inside it and so on, but in S3 the entire `2014/12/01/blah.jpg` it the key - essentially a single long filename. You don't have to create any folders.

Comment: Well, actually I have `Create Folder` option and can create subfolders http://imageshack.com/a/img538/9779/H97CCN.png

Comment: @f1nn Yes, the console and some S3 clients like Transmit use slashes to denote a folder-like structure, to make things easier. If you look at the APIs, though, you'll understand that it's a facade for ease of use.

Comment: oh I got it. If I have no way to affect **real** Amazon fs , then does it mean I can put all files to S3 "in root", and the only requirement for file is to have unique for this bucket filename?

Comment: Yes, you can. However, using this fake folder functionality can be useful, especially with lots of files. Imagine trying to browse the AWS console with 10k files in the root. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html